# Change tab name of Swagger UI

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

Is it possible to change the tab name for Swagger UI:

[image: Swagger UI eample]

I am using Java 17, Spring Boot 3.1.2, `springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui` 2.2.0.

Using the following, but the title does *not* show up as tab name:

```java
@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = "...", version = "1.0", description = "...")})
```

Comment: i don't see any options in the swagger ui configuration to alter the html page title.

Comment: There are some suggestions in the comments here to change the title using custom css https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2304